# Traducir vale de oxxo generado con stripe

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe

Tengo este código html:

```
<form id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="name">
      Name
    </label>
    <input id="name" name="name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="email">
      Email
    </label>
    <input id="email" name="email" required>
  </div>
  <button id="submit-button">Pay with OXXO</button>
 </form>
 <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
 <div id="error-message" role="alert"></div>
 <!-- Success UI for Oxxo -->
 <div class="sr-result-oxxo hidden">
  <h1>¡Gracias! Solo falta un paso más:</h1>
  <div class="sr-instructions">
   <p>
    Instrucciones para realizar el pago en OXXO:
    <p>1. Entregue el voucher con el código de barras a la persona en la caja de cualquier tienda OXXO para que ésta lo escanee.</p>
    <p>2. Proporcione el monto en efectivo a la persona en la caja.</p>
    <p>3. Una vez completado su pago, guarde el recibo para sus archivos.</p>
    <p>4. Para cualquier duda o aclaración, contacte al comerciante.</p>
   </p>
  </div>  
  <table class="sr-tabular-info">
   <tr>
    <th>Monto</th>
    <th>Fecha de expiración</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><span class="order-amount"></span></td>
    <td><span class="oxxo-expiry-date"></span></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <img width="150px" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/4b07d8fe-0ac6-478d-9303-5ed5d5c1220d%2Foxxo.png?v=1571866932777" alt="OXXO logo">
  <div class="oxxo-display"></div>
 </div>
```

**secret.php**

```
<?php
require_once('stripe-lib/init.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_API_KEY');

$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    "amount" => 1099,
    "currency" => "mxn",
    "payment_method_types" => ["oxxo"]
]);

echo json_encode(array('client_secret' => $intent->client_secret));
?>
```

**pay_oxxo.js**

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_API_KEY');

var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  $.post("secret.php",{},function(data){
     var client_Secret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     var clientSecret = client_Secret.client_secret;
      
     stripe.confirmOxxoPayment(
      clientSecret,
      {
        payment_method: {
         billing_details: {
          name: document.getElementById('name').value,
          email: document.getElementById('email').value,
         },
        },
      }) // Stripe.js will open a modal to display the OXXO voucher to your customer
      .then(function(result) {
        // This promise resolves when the customer closes the modal
        if (result.error) {
         // Display error to your customer
         var errorMsg = document.getElementById('error-message');
         errorMsg.innerText = result.error.message;
        }
      }); 
  });
});
});
```

Estoy usando la api de stripe para generar vales para pagar en oxxo, si me genera un vale pero me lo genera en ingles, la pregunta es como hacer para que el texto lo ponga en español por que tampoco me toma en cuenta el `div` que tiene la clase `sr-result-oxxo` que contiene la traducción del texto mostrado en el vale de pago por oxxo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes configurar el idioma del voucher en https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/emails :

[image: Configuración de idioma en el Dashboard de Stripe]

Una vez configurado, se utilizará este idioma para el cupón. También puedes configurar el demo para no mostrar el voucher de Stripe y construir uno propio indicando `{handleActions: false}`:

```
  stripe
    .confirmOxxoPayment(
      clientSecret,
      {
        payment_method: {
          billing_details: {
            name: document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value,
            email: document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value
          }
        }
      },
      {handleActions: false}
    )
```